Can't SSH into Mac
I have a mac (Catalina) I've been SSHing into for a long time with MobaXterm, and am now trying to SSH in from powershell and another mac. On both when I put in my password it just come back asking for the password again. (I know the password is right as that is what I use in MobaXterm). The only possible thing I can see is that in MobaXterm I'm using an SSH-browsewr type of "SFTP protocol".
When doing it from Powershell or the Mac terminal I am simply using 'ssh RPM@192.168.2.60'
output from logging:
(RPM@f01898e9b5db0000) Password:
debug3: send packet: type 61
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: entering
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
(RPM@f01898e9b5db0000) Password:

Any ideas on what I have wrong?

Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [apple.se], [unix.se], or [su].
